# i keep getting error -Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this error:

> I/FirebaseAuth(30112): Creating user with shivamgg3022@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
> W/System  (30112): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> W/LocalRequestInterceptor(30112): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
> W/System  (30112): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> W/LocalRequestInterceptor(30112): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.here is my signup page -

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:confetti/confetti.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:magnet/screens/phoneloginscreen.dart';
import 'package:rounded_loading_button/rounded_loading_button.dart';

import '../common/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../resources/auth_methods.dart';
import '../responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import '../responsive/responsive_layout.dart';
import '../responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import '../utils/colors.dart';
import '../utils/utils.dart';
import '../widgets/text_field_input.dart';
import 'login_screen.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {
  final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _userNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _bioController = TextEditingController();
  final _confirmpasswordController = TextEditingController();
  final _userAgeController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _numberController = TextEditingController();
  final RoundedLoadingButtonController _btnController =
  RoundedLoadingButtonController();
  final TextEditingController _AgeController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _jobTitleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _locationController = TextEditingController();


  bool _isLoading = false;
  Uint8List? _image;
  bool _obscureText = true;
  bool _obscureText2 = true;
  bool _isAccountPublic = true;
  bool _isFirstPart = true;
  // Confetti Animation
  bool isPlaying = false;
  final controller = ConfettiController();
  DateTime? _selectedDate;
  final List<String> genders = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];
  String selectedGender = 'Male';

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // Listen to states: playing, stopped
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = controller.state == ConfettiControllerState.playing;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    nameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    _userNameController.dispose();
    _bioController.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
    _confirmpasswordController.dispose();
    _userAgeController.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1900),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  Widget buildUserDOB() {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        _selectDate(context);
      },
      child: InputDecorator(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Date of Birth',
          hintText: 'Select your date of birth',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        ),
        child: Text(
          _selectedDate != null
              ? '${_selectedDate!.day}/${_selectedDate!.month}/${_selectedDate!.year}'
              : 'Select your date of birth',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void signUpUser() async {
    // Confetti animation
    if (isPlaying) {
      controller.stop();
    } else {
      controller.play();
    }

    // set loading to true
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String formattedDate = _selectedDate != null
        ? "${_selectedDate!.day}/${_selectedDate!.month}/${_selectedDate!.year}"
        : "";

    int userAge = int.tryParse(_AgeController.text) ?? 0;

    // signup user using our authmethodds
    String res = await AuthMethods().signUpUser(
      name: nameController.text,
      email: _emailController.text,
      password: _passwordController.text,
      username: _userNameController.text,
      bio: _bioController.text,
      file: _image!,
      gender: selectedGender,
      number: _numberController.text,
      isAccountPublic: _isAccountPublic,
      birthdate: formattedDate,
      age: userAge,
      jobTitle: _jobTitleController.text,
      location: _locationController.text,
    );
    // if string returned is sucess, user has been created
    if (res == "success") {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      signUp();
      // navigate to the home screen
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ResponsiveLayout(
                  mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
                  webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
                ),
          ),
              (route) => false);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      // show the error
      showSnackBar(context, res);
    }
  }

  selectImage() async {
    Uint8List im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    // set state because we need to display the image we selected on the circle avatar
    setState(() {
      _image = im;
    });
  }

  Future signUp() async {
    try {
      if (passwordConfirmed()) {
        final x = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _emailController.text.trim(),
          password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
        )
            .then((value) {
          Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
            _btnController.success();
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
              _btnController.reset();
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return LoginScreen();
              }));
            });
          });
        });

        final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

        addUserDetails(
            _emailController.text.trim(),
            _userNameController.text.trim(),
            int.parse(_userAgeController.text.trim()),
            user.uid
        );
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
              _btnController.error();
              Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                _btnController.reset();
              });
            });
            return AlertDialog(
              content: Stack(children: [
                Text('Please complete the information, OR'),
                Text('\nThis email has been uesed'),
                Text('\n\nPlease try again !'),
              ]),
            );
          });
    }
  }

  // Future addUserDetails(
  //   String userEmail,
  //   String userName,
  //   int userAge,
  // ) async {
  //   await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add({
  //     'userEmail': userEmail,
  //     'userName': userName,
  //     'userAge': userAge,
  //   });
  // }

  void addUserDetails(String userEmail, String userName, int userAge, String userUID) async {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Users/"+userUID);
    await ref.set({
      "userEmail": userEmail,
      "userName": userName,
      "userAge": userAge,
      "stars": 0,
      "songs_count": 0,
      "rating": 0,
      "img": "https://i.pinimg.com/280x280_RS/2e/45/66/2e4566fd829bcf9eb11ccdb5f252b02f.jpg"
    });
  }
  bool passwordConfirmed() {
    if (_passwordController.text.trim() ==
        _confirmpasswordController.text.trim()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Widget buildCPassword() {
    return TextFieldInput(
      hintText: 'Confirm Password',
      textInputType: TextInputType.text,
      textEditingController: _confirmpasswordController,
      isPass: true,
      obscureText: _obscureText2,
      suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _obscureText2 = !_obscureText2;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          _obscureText2
              ? Icons.visibility
              : Icons.visibility_off,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void goToSecondPart() {
    if (_isFirstPart) {
      // perform necessary validations for the first part here
      setState(() {
        _isFirstPart = false; // Move to the next part
      });
    } else {
      // Show error message or something
    }
  }


  Widget buildFirstPart() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            _image != null
                ? CircleAvatar(
              radius: 64,
              backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            )
                : ClipOval(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 64,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Lottie.asset("assets/profile_pic.json", height: 133),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: -10,
              left: 80,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: selectImage,
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 250,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: TextField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter your name",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Enter your username',
          textInputType: TextInputType.text,
          textEditingController: _userNameController,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Enter your email',
          textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          textEditingController: _emailController,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Enter your password',
          textInputType: TextInputType.text,
          textEditingController: _passwordController,
          isPass: true,
          obscureText: _obscureText,
          suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                _obscureText = !_obscureText;
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              _obscureText
                  ? Icons.visibility
                  : Icons.visibility_off,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        buildCPassword(),
        SizedBox(height: 15,),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Age',
          textInputType: TextInputType.number,
          textEditingController: _AgeController,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Job Title',
          textInputType: TextInputType.text,
          textEditingController: _jobTitleController,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 15,),
        InkWell(
          child: Container(
            child: !_isLoading
                ? const Text(
              'Next',
            )
                : const CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
            decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
              ),
              color: blueColor,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: goToSecondPart,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildSecondPart() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Enter your bio',
          textInputType: TextInputType.text,
          textEditingController: _bioController,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          value: selectedGender,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedGender = value!;
            });
          },
          items: genders.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String gender) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: gender,
              child: Text(gender),
            );
          }).toList(),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Select your gender',
            labelText: 'Gender',
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Enter your number',
          textInputType: TextInputType.phone,
          textEditingController: _numberController,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        buildUserDOB(),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        TextFieldInput(
          hintText: 'Location',
          textInputType: TextInputType.text,
          textEditingController: _locationController,
        ),

        const SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text("Private Account"),
            Switch(
              value: _isAccountPublic,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _isAccountPublic = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            Text("Public Account"),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        InkWell(
          child: Container(
            child: !_isLoading
                ? const Text(
              'Sign Up',
            )
                : const CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: primaryColor,
            ),
            width: double.infinity,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
            decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
              ),
              color: blueColor,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: signUpUser,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 22,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              child: const Text(
                'Already have an account?',
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () =>
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
                    ),
                  ),
              child: Container(
                child: const Text(
                  ' Login.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("Sign Up"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: _isFirstPart ? buildFirstPart() : buildSecondPart(),
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
// ConfettiWidget(
// confettiController: controller,
// shouldLoop: true,
// blastDirectionality: BlastDirectionality.explosive,
// numberOfParticles: 20,
// minBlastForce: 10,
// maxBlastForce: 100,
// emissionFrequency: 0.03,
// gravity: 0.4,
// ),
```

and here is my auth_method code-

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:magnet/dynamic_link_reward/services/code_generator.dart';
import 'package:magnet/main.dart';
import 'package:magnet/models/user.dart' as model;
import 'package:magnet/resources/storage_methods.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../dynamic_link_reward/services/deep_link_service.dart';
import '../screens/login_screen.dart';

class AuthMethods extends GetxController with WidgetsBindingObserver{
  static AuthMethods instance =Get.find();

  late Rx<User?> _user;
  User get user => _user.value!;


  @override
  void onReady() {
    super.onReady();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); // Add the observer
    _user = Rx<User?>(firebaseAuth.currentUser);
    _user.bindStream(firebaseAuth.authStateChanges());
    ever(_user, _setInitialScreen);
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this); // Remove the observer
    super.onClose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);

    // App is in the foreground
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _updateUserOnlineStatus(true);
    }
    // App is in the background
    else if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      _updateUserOnlineStatus(false);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _updateUserOnlineStatus(bool isOnline) async {
    if (_auth.currentUser != null) {
      await _firestore.collection("users").doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid).update({
        'isOnline': isOnline,
      });
    }
  }

  _setInitialScreen(User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAll(() => LoginScreen());
    } else {
      Get.offAll(() => const HomeScreen());
    }
  }

  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // get user details
  Future<model.Users> getUserDetails() async {
    User currentUser = _auth.currentUser!;

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
    await _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();

    return model.Users.fromSnap(documentSnapshot);
  }

  // Signing Up User

  Future<String> signUpUser({
    required String name,
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String username,
    required String bio,
    required Uint8List file,
    required String gender,
    required String number,
    required bool isAccountPublic,
    required String birthdate,
    required int age,
    required String jobTitle,
    required String location,
  }) async {
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty &&
          name.isNotEmpty &&
          password.isNotEmpty &&
          username.isNotEmpty &&
          bio.isNotEmpty &&
          file != null) {
        UserCredential cred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );

        String photoUrl =
        await StorageMethods().uploadImageToStorage('profilePics', file, false);

        final referCode = CodeGenerator.generateCode('refer');
        final referLink = await DeepLinkService.instance?.createReferLink(referCode);
        final Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.now();

        model.Users _user = model.Users(
          name: name,
          username: username,
          uid: cred.user!.uid,
          photoUrl: photoUrl,
          email: email,
          bio: bio,
          followers: [],
          following: [],
          status: "Unavailable",
          groupId: [],
          isOnline: true,
          followRequests: [],
          isAccountPublic: isAccountPublic,
          referLink: referLink,
          referCode: referCode,
          reward: 0,
          referrers: [],
          gender: gender,
          number: number,
          createdAt: DateTime.now(),
          birthdate: birthdate,
          age: age,
          imageUrls: [],
          interests: [],
          jobTitle: jobTitle,
          location: location,
          invitesLeft: 10,
        );

        await _firestore.collection("users").doc(cred.user!.uid).set(_user.toJson());

        await _auth.currentUser!.updateDisplayName(username);

        return "success";
      } else {
        return "Please enter all the required fields";
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return err.toString();
    }
  }

  // logging in user
  Future<String> loginUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    String res = "Some error Occurred";
    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty || password.isNotEmpty) {
        // logging in user with email and password
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        res = "success";
      } else {
        Get.snackbar('Error Creating Account', 'Please enter all the fields');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      Get.snackbar('Error Creating Account', err.toString());
      print(err);
    }
    return res;
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }

  signInWithGoogle() async{
    final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: gAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: gAuth.idToken
    );

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }

}
```

can anyone help me with this i keep getting the error and not able to register new users

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you need to slow down with the login attempts.  You might have spammed the system to the point where it thinks you are abusing it.